# Changing DPI on Windows 10 makes WPF application blury(in realtime)

Tags: wpf, dpi

Simillar question has been asked but I don't think accent was on this.

When I change DPI in Display settings my application becomes blury. If I change DPI settings, than log out and log back in, everything is fine.

My question is - why is OS making my application blury when changing DPI but OS apps like Explorer, Settings, Paint and rest are not blury?

Mentioned OS apps are being resized accordingly to DPI and it is obvious their fonts are crystal clear and crisp. Why is this not happening to my application.

I added dpiAware option in manifest but that doesn't seem to change anything.

Just to note again - I am talking about changing DPI in real time and observing how my application acts and how OS apps act.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [`SnapsToDevicePixels` Property of `UIElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.snapstodevicepixels(v=vs.110).aspx)